# removal - I'd like it removed

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag removal seems to be of no lasting value. Usages of it are ill-defined and the tag is overly broad.

It also has large overlap with [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) in the way I saw it used. In chat I got positive feedback so I went ahead and removed the three occurrences of removal to be found by suggesting edits

Comment: I am disappointed; you didn't use "Removal of [removal]" as your title. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions tagged [removal](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal) have been retagged.

Consider the removal of [removal](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal) complete. (For now, anyway)

[image: Don't ya think this alone deserves an upvote? ;)]